# Tab index lost on tab control's tab page in C# desktop application

Tags: c#

I am working on C# desktop application. I have a tabcontrol. In first tabPage of tabcontrol, I have 15 controls. I have set Tab Index of all controls. But some home tab index is lost when I press Tab on control 5. I see tab index of control 4,5 and 6 is set and all of them are textboxes. After control 5 tab goes to some unknown control and then comes back to control 6. I want to know where does tab index goes. Is there any Tab index change event of tab page?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use "visual tab order" mode to set the tab order ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-the-tab-order-on-windows-forms

[image]

It helps you see the order in design time. I don't believe that individual tabcontrol tabs participate in the tab-key-to-move-focus order. I've always used Tab key to focus the tabcontrol itself then use cursor arrow keys to switch tab pages. The tab key should just shift focus between the visible controls though, as controls inside a panel have a sort of sub-tabindex that the visual mode will represent as 1.1, 1.2 etc. If I had a firm that was a textbox, tabcontrol, then a checkbox on the tabpage in that order, I would expect visual mode to show me  tabindex 1 for the textbox, 2 for the tabpage and 2.1 for the checkbox.. but the checkbox would have a tabindex of 1 (it just shows up as 2.1 in visual mode because it is inside a panel with a tab index of 2)

Things can get a little crazy:

[image]

But enable visual mode and I'm confident you'll see the problem of where your tab index has gone to.  In visual taborder mode you can set the tab indexes by clicking the number you see - click in the order you actually want and the tab index will change

And if it still doesn't work out maybe take a screenshot of your visual tab order mode and add it to your question